# Login with salesforce using AWS Cognito OpenID connect

Tags: salesforce, openid, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to load cognito's web hosted login page to manage login in our web app. In this I want to give salesforce login as well. For this I'm using cognito's openID connect feature. I followed all the steps mentioned in their documentation. Created a connected app in salesforce with openid scope selected, callback url as one of the pages in my web app and start url as cognito userpool's domain with the endpoint 'oauth2/idpresponse'.

But when I click on salesforce login button from cognito's login page it gives me a redirect mismatch error. I noticed that the redirect uri in the request when I hit login with salesforce is pointing to cognito and not to my web app. The redirect uri in the link is my userpool's domain with 'oauth2/idpresponse' endpoint which is start url in connected app. Is there any way that I configure the redirect uri that should append in the salesforce login link from cognito console?

The links I followed :
[Adding OIDC Identity Providers to a User Pool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-oidc-idp.html#cognito-user-pools-oidc-idp-step-2)

And I also tried giving the redirect uri's value(which is the request parameter in the login link created by cognito) as my connected app's callback url. This solved the redirect uri mismatch issue and resulted in causing a different issue saying 'bad token response'. Now I'm confused which way is correct and how to solve these issues.

Please help..

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue authenticating with OKTA...

When you authenticate a user from an identity provider with a User Pool, the "App" that you are authenticating with is the User Pool .. NOT your end application. Therefore, when you configure your App in the identity provider ([SalesForce](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Inside_OpenID_Connect_on_Force.com)) the `redirect_uri` needs to be your User Pool URI (Referencing the link you followed: [Adding OIDC Identity Providers to a User Pool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-oidc-idp.html))

The Authentication Flow then looks something like this:

Request:

User App -> AWS Cognito -> SalesForce

Response:

SalesForce -> AWS Cognito -> User App

You may be redirecting from SalesForce to your User App, which is giving you this redirect mismatch.

For me, I could not configure my User Pool as the App in OKTA (Because I wanted users to initiate Sign-in from OKTA not the app). The approach I took was to use OKTA as an OpenID Federated Identity. Of course I did not get the benefits of the User Pool (Sign-in Page) But for my purposes that was not a requirement.

Comment: Thank you kiteCoder, but I tried that too.. In salesforce I tried giving the callback url as my userpool domain with oauth2/idpresponse as the endpoint(same as the redirect uri parameter in the salesforce login link which is created by cognito) but it is throwing some bad token response error.. So in the example they mentioned our app's uri as callback url so I tried that.. Is there any way to fix bad token error?

Comment: I am trying to use okta as openId provider in cognito. I am invoking okta authn and authorize endpoint from java and successfully getting id_token and access_token. aws cognito-identity get-id using the id_token against the identity pool all I get is Issuer doesn't match providerName. What should be done with /oauth2/idpresponse endpoint in okta? My idea is to get the okta token, get the id for the user from identity pool and use the user pool to get cognito token. All done using java.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact problem and it was that my Callback URL needed to be set to https://[cognito-domain-name].auth.[region].amazoncognito.com/oauth2/idpresponse

This was driving me crazy because the AWS and Salesforce documentation was not adequately explaining this to me.

The most useful writeup I've found was this (Credit: Brian Pfeil
GitHub:pfeilbr): https://github.com/pfeilbr/aws-cognito-playground#salesforce-as-identity-provider-sign-into-app-with-salesforce-credentials

I am stumbling through this setup myself but please feel free to comment with any questions I might be able to clarify.

Comment: The GitHub link is dead

Answer (score 0):

one issue I have faced is the callback URL is in the encoded format in the Cognito hosted UI button URL, and salesforce does not accept the encoded URL. so when both the URLs are matched it gives an invalid URI error